# border-bottom is not showing up on an input div wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to customize the border/outline of an input element so I put a div element as a parent. I want a border to show up when the input element is focused, but right now the bottom of the border is not showing up. I guess it is getting cut off by something.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/63t0oz75/) is a fiddle example

Anyone know why?

js:

```
$('input').focus(
    function(){
        $('.input-container').addClass('is-focused');
}).blur(
    function(){
        $('.input-container').removeClass('is-focused');
});
```

css:

```
.search * {
    height: 35px;
}

.is-focused{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #986fa5;
}

input:focus{
    outline-width: 0px;
}

input{
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="search">
    <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" placeholder="What do you want to learn about?" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not customizing the input border itself?

Comment: works fine for me, what browser + version are you using? (I'm testing in internet explorer)

Comment: as @Finrod said, you can simply use *`:focus`* of *CSS* and simply use *`box-shodow`* or something to create similar effect very easily.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/63t0oz75/ that is the fiddle. it does not work there

Comment: @Finrod the reason is that I want to have a button inside the div and for the border to surround both the button and the input

Answer (score 3):

The border needs a width as well.

```js
$('input').focus(
    function() {
      $('.input-container').addClass('is-focused');
    }).blur(
    function() {
      $('.input-container').removeClass('is-focused');
    });
```

```css
.search * {
  height: 35px;
}
.is-focused {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0; /* top right bottom left */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #986fa5;
}
input:focus {
  outline-width: 0px;
}
input {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" placeholder="What do you want to learn about?" />
  </div>
</div>
```

## Alternative

As alternative, you could do it without JS as well:

```css
.search * {
  height: 35px;
}

input:focus {
  outline-width: 0px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0; /* top right bottom left */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #986fa5;
}
input {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  /* you might need to add this line to get the exact
  same result as the answer above */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  
    <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" placeholder="What do you want to learn about?" />
  
</div>
```

Comment: This works here in this code snippet, but it does not work in my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/63t0oz75/)

Comment: Removing `.search * {
          height: 35px;

        }` fixes that. So I'm guessing that the input somehow overlaps it's parent. Maybe only set height to `.search` or to the input.

Comment: the reason I have that is because I have a few decedents which I want to make have the same height. but you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use Javascript for this, and just use the `:focus` pseudo selector to style the input:

**CSS**

```
.search * {
      height: 35px;

}

input{
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
}

input:focus{
      outline-width: 0px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #986fa5;
      border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I want to have a border around both the input and a search button, that's why i don't want to use your solution